# Is it possible to programmatically set a request context path from inside the servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

This is a special case where I am stuck dealing with an "enterprise" webapp. The enterprise app is calling `request.getContext()` and comparing it to another string.

I see I can get the servlet context path using getServletContext.getContextPath(). Is it possible to set the request context path from inside a servlet?

Comment: I assume that you're talking about `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()` since there's no such method as `HttpServletRequest#getContext()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set it, but you can change its outcome with help of [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html).

```
public class MyRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public MyRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override    
    public String getContextPath() {
        return "a different context path"; // TODO: implement accordingly.
    }

}
```

Create a `Filter` which does basically the following in `doFilter()` method and map it as an early filter on URL pattern of interest.

```
chain.doFilter(new MyRequest((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**, It gets set when you deploy your app. You can't change it once it is deployed